# PHP check if file locked with flock()?

Tags: php, filesystems, file-locking, flock

Will `fopen()` fail if a file exists, but is currently locked with `LOCK_EX`?

Or do I have to open it, and then try and *set* a lock, in order to determine if one already exists?

I've also read that `flock()` will;

> pause [the script] untill you get the lock for indefinite amount of time or till your script times out
>
> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php#95257

If so, is it true this 'pause' can be by-passed with;

```
if (!flock($f, LOCK_SH | LOCK_NB)) {
    // file locked, do something else
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`flock()` doesn't actually prevent you from reading/writing to a file, it only allows you to "communicate" the ideas of locking to other scripts. You can detect if there is a lock on a file using the snippet you posted.