# Skip reading/writing to a file while someone is writing to it?

Tags: php, file-locking

How can i know if someone is writing to a file , so i can skip writing or reading it ?
file-locking could be used here , but there are some problems found ! like this one : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54453

Any other ideas ?

I want to skip writing/reading to a file without waiting for the file to be unlocked like the case in `LOCK_EX` or `LOCK_SH` , where code hangs till file is unlocked !

Comment: If you control access to the file, then don't use the buggy locks and you'll be fine.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149324/php-check-if-file-locked-with-flock) may be useful

Comment: @ user973254 not working
@Marc , couldn't understand you

Comment: @ronan: if your code is the only code/app that touches that file, then you'll KNOW what kind of locks are in use and don't have to worry about lock_nb being buggy.

Comment: @MarcB yes my code is the only one that plays with those files , the question is how to know it is locked without the buggy flock and its friends ?

Comment: There's always the old standby of a flag file you create while fiddling with the file, and then remove afterwards.